# Is it better to have a listenner attached to the window for all components or one listenner by component?

Tags: javascript, angular, vuejs2

In my **Vue JS 2.0 app**, I have to display some elements **when the viewport reach** them.

So when my components are `created()`, each of them, add a Scroll Listener like this: `window.addEventListener("scroll", displayElementFunction)` and remove it when `beforeDestroy()` event triggers or when the element I want to display are displayed.

I like this idea because each component are **independant**.

But I do not like the idea to have **multiple scroll listenners** on a single page where, in theory, I would just need one listenner.

This issue applies to other JS framework like Angular or React.

Comment: In general I would say that that one listener per component is a better solution, because of the clear separation of the components. But the `scroll`  event is an event that is fired at a high rate, and you normaly want to add some kind of throtteling if you work with this event and doing this over and over again for multiple components is not the best idea.

Comment: @t.niese why not? if it's separated then in each component the best throttling level can be configured